# How to add Multi-threading to RMI project?

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

I am new to RMI world. I have one server and multiple clients. the server expose one and only one object in the main. this pretty object has a lot of methods (services to clients), and all of the clients use the same services (access the same services). I want to update my current project to use threads. I don't know what exactly what should be replaced by `Runnable`. I think that I might make the single object, which the server exposed, as `Runnable`. but I wonder how the client may interact with the object in this situation.
please refer me to Any references you know to be familiar with this topic.

I don't want any code, but If there is a project that had faced the same problem you are engaged to share it with me. I need your ideas to design my solution.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Considered bouncing into an EE environment?

Comment: Could you please explain this a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to update my current project to use threads.

Your project already uses threads. RMI is multithreaded. Two clients can and will execute methods on your remote object(s) simultaneously. It is up to you to *prevent* that in the appropriate places, by using synchronization or semaphores where you have non-thread-safe data structures for example.

> I don't know what exactly what should be replaced by Runnable. I think that I might make the single object, which the server exposed, as Runnable. but I wonder how the client may interact with the object in this situation.

You don't need to implement `Runnable` or anything else. Multi-threading in RMI is already happening in your current code. What you need to pay attention to is not multi-threading, but thread *safety* of your code.

> please refer me to Any references you know to be familiar with this topic.

See the [RMI Specification, #3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch3.html). The language used there sometimes confuses people, but what it means is that you *cannot asssume RMI is single-threaded.*

Comment: thanks, this makes me happy :) but this means that my exposed object runs on a different thread for each client. is that true?

Comment: A different thread per *concurrent* client, yes.